# host entry in android

Tags: android-emulator, dns, hosts, uat

what is the procedure to put an host Entry in android host file?
we did the followings.
An Entry for the URL was made in hosts file of the Android using cmd ( File Explorer -> System -> etc ->hosts ).

```
127.0.0.1               localhost
xx.xx.xx.xx             www.example.com
```

For Reference please visit
http://www.bradcurtis.com/2011/02/13/hosts-file-google-android-emulator/

But When we execute the program, the host entry is not read by android. It is going for DNS to get the ip for which we have already made an entry in hosts file.

Can anyone suggest how to add an entry in hosts file of Android so that the entry can be read while the program is executed.

Comment: Which version of android, and are you using a wifi network with a proxy when you did this test?

Comment: @user3788685 I just ran into similar problem, I was able to fix it by adding a new line at the hosts file.